# Making drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development sorry. ok so i want to make html and css menu drop when you click on it. i google and all i could find was menus which expand when you hover over them.

basically i want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD7WD.jpg)

so far i have tried this

CSS

```
.menu-item {
  background: #fff;
  width: 50px; 
}
.menu-item ul {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
}
.menu-item ul {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 0px; 
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
}
.menu-item:focus ul {
  height: 93px;
}
.menu-item h4 a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="menu-item">
  <h4>&#x25BC;</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

i would also be very pleased if you guys can give me link to any tutorial which would help me make this menu.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery for making it simple. It is a JavaScript file which provides you ease for creating such menus with ease. One of them which is easy to use can be found here: http://patrickkunka.github.io/easydropdown/

Comment: Every web solution should remain fully functional when Javascript is disabled.

Comment: I have one question.Is the js file needed to make easydropdown work available in a CDN?